# Unblr to convert checkbox to radio button

Tags: jquery, html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#change').click(function () {
            if ($('#change:checked').length > 0) {
                var myType = "checkbox";
            } else {
                var myType = "radio";
            }
           var checkbox = $("#Radio1");
            checkbox.replaceWith('<input type="' + myType + '" name="option1"/>');

    });
 </script>
```

**html**

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="change" id="change"/>
  <label for="changem">Change Buttons</label>
     <br/>
     <br/>
 <input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="option1" value="answer1"/>
```

When I click a checkbox radio button is converting to checkbox but unclicking is not converting it into radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- You forgot to assign an id for the button when you replaced its contents so the next time your `$('#Radio1')` selector returns nothing
- You declared the `myType` variable inside the `if` which is local to this scope.
- You didn't properly close the `})` between the `document.ready` handler and the `click` handler.

Here's what I would recommend you:

```
$(function() {
    $('#change').change(function () {
        var myType = 'radio';
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            myType = 'checkbox';
        }

        $('#Radio1').replaceWith(
            $('<input/>', {
                id: 'Radio1',
                name: 'option1',
                type: myType
            })
        );
    });
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8SQJn/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You replace the current input tag with a new one. But don't give the new input tag an id.

```
'<input type="' + myType + '" id="change" name="option1"/>'
```